# Ubuntu on nvidia tegra 2 (motorola xoom 3g)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Can I flash Nexus 7 image of Ubuntu 13.04 on Motorola Xoom? Both devices have nearly same hardware except the processor and screen and also the 3G.

Comment: I am pretty sure Nexus 7 has Tegra3 and not Tegra2, which makes the answer no.

Answer (score 0):

If the architecture of the chips turns out to be similar enough to run the same build then the follow up questions would be if the build can support the other chips that are different from the Nexus to the Xoom and not leave a xoom essentially bricked for the effort in one way or another. I will try and find a list of chips such as wifi and such in the specs of each.

Answer (score 0):

I know the architecture between tegra 3 and 2 are different enough that the android 4.2 gesture keyboard does not work on tegra 2 at all, and it does on tegra 3. That is just one example of a known incompatibility. I'm sure there are plenty more, especially in the drivers. Personally, I wouldn't even try it. But if you really want to try it out, just make sure you do a full backup, because I really don't think it will work. The processors are very different in ways that are more than just the amount of cores.